# ks and chisquare test reject equality of distributions for data coming from same DGP

Tags: python, distribution, chi-squared

I generated two distributions using the following code:

```
rand_num1 = 2*np.random.randn(10000) + 1
rand_num2 = 2*np.random.randn(10000) + 1
stats.ks_2samp(rand_num1, rand_num2)
```

**My question is why do both these distributions do not test to be the same based on kstest and chisquare test.**

When I run a kstest on the 2 distributions I get:

```
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.019899999999999973, pvalue=0.037606196570126725)
```

which implies that the two distributions are statistically different. I use the following code to plot the CDF of the two distributions:

```
count1, bins = np.histogram(rand_num1, bins = 100)
count2, _ = np.histogram(rand_num2, bins = bins)
plt.plot(np.cumsum(count1), 'g-')
plt.plot(np.cumsum(count2), 'b.')
```

[This is how the CDF of two distributions looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkL3V.png).

When I run a chisquare test I get the following:

```
stats.chisquare(count1, count2) # Gives an nan output
stats.chisquare(count1+1, count2+1) # Outputs "Power_divergenceResult(statistic=180.59294741316694, pvalue=1.0484033143507713e-06)"
```

I have 3 questions below:

1. Even though the CDF looks the same and the data comes from same distribution why do kstest and chisquare test both reject the same distribution hypothesis? Is there an underlying assumption that I am missing here?
2. Some counts are 0 and hence the first chisquare() gives an error. Is it an accepted practice to just add a non-0 number to all counts to get a correct estimate?
3. Is there a kstest to test against non standard distributions, say a normal with a non 0 mean and std != 1?

Comment: Strange, really. I just ran your K-S example and consistently getting values like `(statistic=0.011, pvalue=0.57)`, which looks about right. What value are you getting for `stats.ks_2samp(rand_num1, rand_num1)` (ditto for num2) ? Output should be `(0,1)`.

Comment: I've put `np.random.seed(12345)` upfront, got K-S back with `(statistic=0.010, pvalue=0.61)`, Python 3.5.1 x64 Anaconda

Comment: for stats.ks_2samp(rand_num1, rand_num1) I get p-value = 1.0 (expected). You are right - in most cases I get a non significant p-value.
I am particularly concerned with the case I posted - the CDFs of the distributions is so similar and even then both kstest and chisquare test imply they are different. 
Even when kstest says they are same (p-val > 0.5) chisquare test rejects them to be same.

Comment: ok, not sure I got good answer, but lets start with something

Answer (score 0):

CDF, in my humble opinion, is not a good curve to look at. It will hide a lot of details due to the fact that it is an integral. Basically, some outlier in distribution which is way below will be compensated by another outlier which is way above.

Ok, lets take a look at distribution of K-S results. I've run the test 100 times and plotted statistics vs p-value, and, as expected, for some cases there would be (small p, large stat) points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(12345)

x = []
y = []

for k in range(0, 100):
    rand_num1 = 2.0*np.random.randn(10000) + 1.0
    rand_num2 = 2.0*np.random.randn(10000) + 1.0

    q = stats.ks_2samp(rand_num1, rand_num2)

    x.append(q.statistic)
    y.append(q.pvalue)

plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

Graph

[image]

UPDATE

> In reality if I run a test and see the test vs control distribution of my metric as shown in my plot then I would want to be able to say that they are they same - are there any statistics or parameters around these tests that can tell me how close these distributions are?

Of course, they are - and you're using one of such tests! K-S is most general but weakest test. And as with any test you would use there are ALWAYS cases where test will say those samples come from different distributions even you deliberately sample them from the same routine. It is just NATURE of the things,
you'll get `yes` or `no` with some confidence, but not much more. Look
at the graph again for illustrations.

Concerning your exercises with chi2 I'm very skeptical from the beginning to use chi2 for such task. For me, given the problem of making decision about two samples, test to be used should be explicitly symmetric. K-S is ok, but looking at the definition of chi2, it is NOT symmetric. Simple modification of
your code

```
count1, bins = np.histogram(rand_num1, bins = 40, range=(-2.,2.))
count2, _    = np.histogram(rand_num2, bins = bins, range=(-2.,2.))

q = stats.chisquare(count2, count1)
print(q)

q = stats.chisquare(count1, count2)
print(q)
```

produces something like

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=87.645335824746468, pvalue=1.3298580128472864e-05)
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=77.582358201839526, pvalue=0.00023275129585256563)
```

Basically, it means that test may pass if you run `(1,2)` but fail if you run `(2,1)`, which is not good, IMHO. Chi2 is ok with me as soon as you test against expected values from known distribution curve - here test asymmetry makes sense

I would advice to try Anderson-Darling test along the lines

```
q = stats.anderson_ksamp([np.sort(rand_num1), np.sort(rand_num2)])
print(q)
```

But remember, it is the same as with K-S, some samples may fail to pass the test even if they are drawn from the same underlying distribution - this is just the nature of the beast.

UPDATE: Some reading material

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187016/scipy-chisquare-applied-on-continuous-data

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I guess this answers the first qn by saying that the rejections (small p-value) are due to type-1 errors.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I guess this answers the first qn by saying that the rejections (small p-value) are due to type-1 errors.
In reality if I run a test and see the test vs control distribution of my metric as shown in my plot then I would want to be able to say that they are they same - are there any statistics or parameters around these tests that can tell me how close these distributions are?
And any thoughts on the last 2 questions?